# Magento upgrade log error

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am trying to upgrade my magento core files from the magento connect manager and am getting this error in the servers log

ModSecurity: Output filter: Failed to read bucket (rc 70007): The timeout specified has expired [hostname "example.com"] [uri "/downloader/index.php"] [unique_id "fn0Uy8TcOYwACDnJBXIAAAAL"]

Can anybody please shed some light on this?

Thanks,
Evan

Answer (score 0):

Your request has timed out , for upgrading:

- turn off all custom extensions
- turn off modSecurity
- turn off custom templates (default template)
- perform upgrade
- turn on your template and extensions one by one and debug